# How to insert a normal distribution into another function?

Tags: normal-distribution, convolution, rayleigh-distribution

I am struggling with the following problem.
TLDR: I want to merge the uncertainty of the normal distribution into another function.

Imagine a certain significant wave height (Hs) of 2 metres in a sea state. One wants to know the Most Probable Maximum (MPM) of the largest wave that passes by in a certain period of time (3 hours). This is done by the following formula:

```
f_mpm = ((np.exp(-x**2/(2*m0)) * (1 - np.exp(-x**2/(2*m0)))**(N-1) * N*x) / m0)
```

$$
f_{mpm} = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2m_0}} * (1 - e^{-\frac{x^2}{2m_0}})^{N-1}*N*x}{m_0}
$$
Where:

N = 10800 / Tm (3 hours divided by the mean period of the waves)

Tm = 10 s --> N ~= 1000

m0 = (Hs/2)^2

However, let's say that the Hs is not known but normally distributed, as it is a forecast.

```
f_normal = 1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * np.exp(-(x-np.sqrt*(4*m0)**2/(2*sigma**2))
```

$$
\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} * e^{-\frac{\left(x-\sqrt{4*m_0}\right)^2}{2*\sigma^2}}
$$
Is there a way to (analytically) merge the two functions to calculate the MPM based on an uncertainty?

Below I included a graph of the two functions. If the solution was plotted as well, it would result in a flatter and wider yellow line.
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $m_0 = (\frac{Hs}{2})^2 = 1$? This suggests $m_0 = 1$, which means that Hs is not actually random. Also, what is $x$?

Comment: m0 is just another representation of Hs. As I chose Hs = 2 for this case, it followed that m0 = 1. But it is a variable. X is used to plot the graphs and is an array of 0 to 10 in this case.

Comment: Since Hs is random, then you may be interested in the probability density function of $f_{mpm}$, in which case [this](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_3_functions_continuous_var.php) is helpful. If finding the PDF this way is difficult, you could then generate many samples of Hs, pass them through the $f_{mpm}$ function, then estimate the PDF based on the output samples.

Comment: Thank you. Actually $f_{mpm}$ is a PDF. It already is a differentiated Rayleigh CDF to the power N: $$ f_{mpm} = \frac{d}{dx}(F_{Rayleigh}^N) $$ I already did do a numerical analysis where I took samples of Hs and calculated the MPM. This resulted in a histogram with the results. I was wondering however, if it is possible to do it analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of the random variable mpm given $Hs=y$ has density
$$
f_{mpm|Hs}(x|y) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \left(\frac{y}{2} \right)^2}} * (1 - e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \left(\frac{y}{2} \right)^2}})^{N-1}*N*x}{\left(\frac{y}{2} \right)^2}
$$

The marginal distribution of the random variable mpm is found by integrating the joint distribution over the variable $y$:
$$
f_{mpm}(x) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \left(\frac{y}{2} \right)^2}} * (1 - e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \left(\frac{y}{2} \right)^2}})^{N-1}*N*x}{\left(\frac{y}{2} \right)^2} \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} * e^{-\frac{\left(y-\sqrt{4*m_0}\right)^2}{2*\sigma^2}} dy
$$

This integral cannot be found analytically.

I understand that it appears that  $Hs$ is almost always positive since the $\sigma$ is small. However, for the normal distribution, negative values are possible and therefore the normal distribution might not be appropriate. I searched online and cannot find any distributions that are conjugate for the ordinary Rayleigh distribution, let alone the distribution you have here.

I am not sure what your goal is here. Do you have some data and you want to find the maximum likelihood estimates of all the parameters in the joint distribution?

Comment: Thanks John! The reason I am trying to do this is related to wave forecasting. A significant wave height is forecasted, but is not exactly known. Therefore, a normal dist. is applied. To determine a safety factor on this spread, a Rayleigh Most Probable Maximum needs to be calculated. From there one can evaluate it, but that is out of this scope.

Comment: I plotted your function and it works. Many thanks!!